# Access cells in other file with variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm taking info from one file to another, using: (**7.xlsx** is the file name)

```
Cells(13, 4).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[7.xlsx]sheet1!R3C5"
```

In this situation, I am taking the information from C5 spot. *But* I want to take the info not from this spot only, but from different spots, using loop.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 3 To 17
    Cells(i, 4).Select // works fine
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[7.xlsx]sheet1!R3C5" // I want to put the
                                                   // "i" instead of the C
```

Any idea how I can do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try: "=[7.xlsx]sheet1!R3" & i & "5"

Comment: @Wernerson Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to replace `C` as it signifies the column in `RC` notation.

If you want to change the row then use this

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[7.xlsx]sheet1!R" & i & "C5"
```

If you want to change the column then use this

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[7.xlsx]sheet1!R3C" & i
```

Note that in RC notation, R1C1 means Cell A1. Changing `C` will give you an error.

Comment: That's it. Thank you! The "FormulaR1C1" part, is for using the formula in the A1 cell?

Comment: You can use either `.FormulaR1C1` or `.Formula`. The former uses `R1C1` notation and the latter uses `A1` notation

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks you!